# Why is the player multiplying?

Tags: java, arrays, debugging, multidimensional-array

The sample code below is in two classes, World and Driver
World Class:

```
public class World {

    private char[][] world2D;
    private int characterRow;
    private int characterColumn;
    private int score;
    private int collision = 0;

    public World(int width, int height){
        world2D = new char[width][height];
        characterColumn = 0;
        characterRow = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < world2D.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < world2D[i].length; j++){
                world2D[i][j] = '-';
            }
        }

        world2D[characterRow][characterColumn] = 'P';
    }

    public void moveUp(){
        world2D[characterRow][characterColumn] = '-';
        if (characterRow > 0){
            characterRow -= 1;
        }
        world2D[characterRow][characterColumn] = 'P';
        score ++;
    }

    public void moveDown(){
        world2D[characterRow][characterColumn] = '-';
        if (characterRow < world2D.length){
            characterRow += 1;
        }
        world2D[characterRow][characterColumn] = 'P';
        score ++;
    }

    public void moveRight(){
        world2D[characterRow][characterColumn] = '-';
        if (characterColumn < (world2D[characterRow].length - 1)){
            characterColumn += 1;
        }
        world2D[characterRow][characterColumn] = 'P';
        score ++;
    }

    public void moveLeft(){
        world2D[characterRow][characterColumn] = '-';
        if (characterColumn > 0){
            characterColumn -= 1;
        }
        world2D[characterRow][characterColumn] = 'P';
        score ++;
    }
    public int getScore(){
        return score;
    }

    public void displayWorld(){
        for(int i = 0; i < world2D.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < world2D[i].length; j++){
                System.out.print(world2D[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }       
    }
    public int getCollision(){
        return collision;
    }

    public int getCharacterRow(){
        return characterRow;
    }

    public void addRock(){
        int lastRow = world2D.length - 1;
        int width = world2D[lastRow].length - 1;
        int rockPosition = (int) (Math.random()*width);
        if (world2D[lastRow][rockPosition] != 'P'){
            world2D[lastRow][rockPosition] = '@';
        }
        if (world2D[lastRow][rockPosition] == 'P'){
            collision = 1;
        }

    }
    public void shiftWorldUp(){
        for(int row = 0; row < world2D.length - 2; row++){
            world2D[row] = world2D[row + 1];
            }
        //world2D[characterRow][characterColumn] = 'P';
    }

}
```

And Driver Class with the main method:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How tall should the world be?: ");
        int height = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("How wide should the world be?: ");
        int width = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("To move type 'up', 'down', 'left' or 'right");

        World myWorld = new World(width,height);

        while (myWorld.getCollision() != 1){
            String nextMove = input.nextLine();
            if (nextMove.equals("up")){
                myWorld.moveUp();
            }
            else if (nextMove.equals("down")){
                myWorld.moveDown();
            }
            else if (nextMove.equals("left")){
                myWorld.moveLeft();
            }
            else if (nextMove.equals("right")){
                myWorld.moveRight();
            }
            myWorld.displayWorld();
            myWorld.addRock();
            myWorld.shiftWorldUp();
            System.out.println("Next move?: ");

        }
    }

}
```

When I try to execute the code I get a weird error where multiple parts of the array are filled with the 'P' character like below:

```
How tall should the world be?: 6
How wide should the world be?: 6
To move type 'up', 'down', 'left' or 'right
P-----
------
------
------
------
------
Next move?: 
down
------
P-----
------
------
------
@-----
Next move?: 
down
P-----
------
P-----
P-----
P-----
@---@-
Next move?:
```

I can't find this bug. It's kind of a fun one so I hope someone can help me find it!

Comment: When you do shiftWorldUp you don't erase the P?

Comment: How would I go about doing that in the shiftWorldUp method?

Comment: What is supposed to happen to the player when the world shifts up?

Comment: The row with the @ sign or "rock" is supposed to move up to the next row and the bottom row should become populated with another "rock"